# c# Visual Studio 2015 - how to create a Setup which uninstall other application

Tags: c#, installation, uninstallation

Initially I created an application that I completely rewrite in a second version. It is a complete different Visual studio solution.
Now I would like that its Setup installer uninstall the previous version but because it was not created using the same solution, the automatic uninstallation of previous version does not work.

Is there any way to force the installer to uninstall certain application based on product name or product code?

I found a WMIC command that works when run from command line

```
wmic product where name="XXXX" call uninstall /nointeractive
```

So I created a VBS script which execute a bat file containing the WMIC code and I added it to the Setup project

```
dim shell
set shell=createobject("wscript.shell")
shell.run "uninstallAll.bat",0,true
set shell=nothing
```

but when I run the result MSI, it fires an error 1001, meaning that a service already exists. , in other words the uninstallation didn't work. 
The old program is still present and they create a service with the same name. :/

any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 options:

1. You can increase the version of MSI project so it will treat as upgrade and it will not throw any error while installing.
2. another way out is the write some in the installer project as follows:

   ```
   protected override void OnBeforeInstall(IDictionary savedState)
   {
       //Write uninstall powershell script
       //installutil /u <yourproject>.exe 
       using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
       {
           PowerShellInstance.AddScript("");
           PowerShellInstance.AddParameter("");
       }
       PowerShellInstance.Invoke();        
   }
   ```

Note:  This InstallUtil is available with the .NET Framework, and its path is `%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework[64]\<framework_version>`.

For example, for the 32-bit version of the .NET Framework 4 or 4.5.*, if your Windows installation directory is `C:\Windows`, the path is `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe`.

For the 64-bit version of the .NET Framework 4 or 4.5.*, the default path is `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe`

Answer (score 0):

I decided to go for the option of introducing c# code in the project installer. Firstly I added the reference for System.Management.Automation via nuget

https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Management.Automation

After this, I just created a string variable containing the PS code I need to uninstall several programs with a similar name.

```
 string unInstallKiosk = @"$app = get-WMIObject win32_Product -Filter ""name like 'KIOSK'"" 
                    foreach ($program in $app){ 
                    $app2 = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Where -Object { $_.IdentifyingNumber -match ""$($program.identifyingNumber)""    
                    } 
                    $app2.Uninstall()}";
```

and passed this variable to the method PowerShellInstance.AddScript()

```
  PowerShellInstance.AddScript(unInstallKiosk);
```

The installation ends but the uninstallation simply dont happens.

anyone has an idea how to solve this?